# Using FFMPEG in an OS X application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ffmpeg, live-streaming

so I've been wanting to make a real-time live streaming application. Essentially, the application would send the microphone feed from an Xcode application to a website where it can be viewed in real-time. Is FFMPEG the best solution for this? How would I go about doing this? If that's too broad, then how do I use the FFMPEG framework in an OS X objective-c application?

Comment: Run a search with '[objective-c] ffmpeg.'

Comment: Hi El Tomato! Thanks for the response! I've been looking at the wrapper here: https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper but I'm not sure how to use it with Xcode...

Comment: and how would I stream live audio with this FFmpeg wrapper? It doesn't seem like I can use normal FFmpeg commands

Answer (score 0):

To directly address your questions:

> (1) Is FFMPEG the best solution for this?

It depends. When setting up a live streaming environment you will likely stumble over FFMPEG, VLC and gstreamer, which are the options you have to simply stream video/audio. Therefore, yes, FFMPEG can be used as part of the solution. Please look into the following question: [DIY Video Streaming Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228035/diy-video-streaming-server/35574998#35574998)

> (2) How would I go about doing this?

Your requirement is to make a live streaming application which sends the mic input onto the web. This includes the following steps:

(0) Your Xcode application will need to provide a method to start this process. You don't necessarily need to integrate a framework to achieve this.

(1) Streaming / Restreaming

Use FFMPEG or VLC to grab your device and stream it locally:

```
ffmpeg -i audioDevice -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 48k -f rtp rtp://host:port
```

(2) Segmenting for HTTP Live Streaming*

Use a segmenter such as: [mediastreamsegmenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745-CH1-MEDIASTREAMSEGMENTATION) (Apple), [livehttp](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Streaming_for_the_iPhone/) (VLC) or [segment](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) (FFMPEG) to prepare your stream for web delivery:

```
vlc -vvv -I dummy <SOURCEADDRESS> --sout='#transcode{acodec=libfaac,ab=48}:std{access=livehttp{seglen=10,delsegs=false,numsegs=10,index=/path/to/your/index/prog_index.m3u8,index-url=YourUrl/fileSequence######.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=/path/to/your/ts/files/fileSequence######.ts}'
```

*you could also simply use VLC to grab your audiodevice with qtsound (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538426/how-to-capture-microphone-input-in-vlc/12277592#12277592)) and prepare it for streaming with livehttp.

(3) HTML 5 Delivery

Publish your stream

```
<audio>
<source src="YOUR_PATH/playlist.m3u8" />
</audio>
```

> (3) If that's too broad, then how do I use the FFMPEG framework in an OS X objective-c application?

Either use an external wrapper framework to access FFMPEG functionality and consult the tutorials to work with these frameworks or you could also approach this by using `NSTask` to wrap your command line arguments in Objective-C and simply start those tasks from your application - as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8148824/693052).

Another way would be to use [VLCKit](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=VLCKit), which offers VLC functionality in a framework for Objective-C ([VLCKit wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/)). However when tackling streaming challenges I prefer to work with the actual commands instead of pushing another layer of framework in between, which may be missing some options.

---

I hope this points you in the right directions. There are multiple ways to solve this. It's a broad question, therefore this broad approach to answer your question.